# Given a point A (3,4) What is the smallest segment passing through A and makes a right triangle with the coordinates

Tags: calculus

> Given  a point A (3,4) 
>   What is the smallest segment passing through A and makes a right triangle with the coordinates ?

I need help with this question please?  I know that i have to write my own work ; but i really didn't understand how to do that !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any (non-vertical) line can be written y= ax+ b.  The fact that the line goes through (3, 4) means that 4= 3a+ b so b= 4- 3a.  Write the line as y= ax+ 4- 3a.  That crosses the y-axis when x= 0: y= 4- 3a so at the point (0, 4- 3a).  That crosses the x-axis when y= 0: ax+ 4- 3a so ax= 3a- 4, x= 3- 4/a so at the point (3- 4/a, 0).  The distance between those points is $\sqrt{(3- 4a)^2+ (3- 4/a)^2}= \sqrt{9- 24a+ 16a^2+ 9- 24/a+ 16/a^2}$.  You want to minimize that.  It is fairly easy to see that $\sqrt{f(x)}a$ is minimized when f(x).  That is, the problem is to minimize $16a^2- 24a- 24/a+ 16/a^2+ 18$

Answer (score 1):

You could just doodle it. The solution has to do with this question: On which side of the line $x=y$ is the point?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you understand that $(3,4)$ means that the point is at a distance of $3$ units $\textbf{from}$ $y-axis$ and similarly $4$ units $\textbf{from}$ $x-axis$. You get the answer now, right? Respond in comments if you need more help; although I'd suggest that you try to draw in yourself and see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Let the equation of the straight line be $$\dfrac xa+\dfrac yb=1$$

As it passes through $(3,4)$  $$\dfrac 3a+\dfrac4b=1$$

WLOG $a=3\sec^2t, b=4\csc^2t$

We need to minimize $$(3\sec^2t)^2+(4\csc^2t)^2$$

Use [Second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second_derivative_test_.28single_variable.29)